# change data and get very wired output (simple linear regression)

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

this is a very simple sample, it is like homework something. code is below:

```
x_data = np.array([0.35252703, 0.60587817, 0.8906856, 0.4813087, 0.53391305, 0.27751151])
y_data = x_data * 10

b = tf.Variable(0.)
k = tf.Variable(0.)
y = k * x_data + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_data - y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(400):
        sess.run(train)
        if (step % 40 == 0):
            print(step, sess.run([k, b]))
```

this output is:
0 [1.2522789, 2.0945494]
40 [5.304193, 2.5357442]
80 [7.116992, 1.5568293]
120 [8.229965, 0.95582175]
160 [8.913281, 0.58682966]
200 [9.332804, 0.36028674]
240 [9.590374, 0.22119847]
280 [9.748508, 0.13580598]
320 [9.845596, 0.083378375]
360 [9.905204, 0.0511902]
it is pretty good. then i changed data this way:

```
x_data = np.array([352.52703, 605.87817, 0.8906856, 0.4813087, 0.53391305, 0.27751151])
```

then output is 
0 [327576.72, 640.39246]
40 [nan, nan]
80 [nan, nan]
120 [nan, nan]
160 [nan, nan]
200 [nan, nan]
240 [nan, nan]
280 [nan, nan]
320 [nan, nan]
360 [nan, nan]

anyone can tell me why the second output is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the learning rate smaller.

I set the learning rate to be 1e-5 and it works fine.

`

```
(0, [16.378834, 0.032019623])
(40, [9.9999628, 0.019538468])
(80, [9.9999628, 0.019527739])
(120, [9.9999628, 0.01951701])
(160, [9.9999628, 0.019506281])
(200, [9.9999628, 0.019495552])
(240, [9.9999628, 0.019484824])
(280, [9.9999628, 0.019474095])
(320, [9.9999628, 0.019463366])
(360, [9.9999628, 0.019452637])
```

`

you initialize the k and b to be 0, the initial gradient is big, and the learning rate is big, so it just goes opposite to the right answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is a pretty good way to solve this problem. Could you tell me what or why cause this my problem? And is there any document or textbook to explain these relations between k, b, gradient and learning rate, or explain how these elements work together and impact each other

Comment: @Frank if you are interested in this, you can go to Coursera and join the maching learning taught by Ang, which is a good start point.